# inline image captions plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there such thing as an inline image caption plugin for jquery?

So a user can someone select a point on an image, and then insert a text caption.  Whenever someone hovers over the image, the caption displays.

Flickr has this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keywords you're looking for are **jquery photo tagging**. A quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+photo+tagging) turns up numerous results, mostly tutorials on rolling your own.

This looks informative:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1837-Creating-Flickr-Style-Photo-Tagging-With-jQuery.htm